# How to store the number of rows returned using SELECT in a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I want to store the number of rows returned from the SELECT statement in a variable, as i require the count for further calculations.
I tried using the COUNT function, but I don't know how to store it in a variable. Please help me out. Any alternate method would do too.
Thanks in advance.

```
 #!C:/Perl64/bin/Perl.exe

 use warnings;
 use strict;
 use autodie;
 use Data::Dumper;
 use DBI;

 my $db="hnf1a";
 my $user="root";
 my $password="";
 my $host="localhost";
 my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:$host",$user,$password);
 my $sth=$dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT ano AS $b FROM mody where ano = ?');
 my $input = <stdin>;
 my @num = split //, $input;

 for my $num(@num){     
 say "rows matching input <$num>:";     
 $sth->execute($num);   
 while(my@data = $sth->fetchrow_array){     
 say"\t@data";  
 }}
```

So in my code i need to find a way to store the number of rows returned.

Comment: The number of rows returned from *which* query? It looks like you’re probably running several for each input. What have you tried so far? I don’t see any code that indicates an attempt at doing anything you’ve asked for help with.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the line. I have edited the post. The rows from the select ano query

Comment: What is the `AS $b` for? Normally you’d write `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` if you wanted to know the number of matching rows.

Comment: Also, `stdin` is not one of the standard I/O handles. You probably meant `STDIN`.

Comment: In an attempt to store the counted rows in a variable I used AS $b.

Comment: Don’t do that. It seems like you might have a misunderstanding about the interaction between Perl and a database.

Comment: Is there any other way I can store the counted rows?

Comment: Did you not read what I said a few comments up?

Comment: I will try that method

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:', '', '', {
    RaiseError => 1,
    PrintError => 0,
}) or die $DBI::errstr;

$dbh->do(q{
    create table mody (
        ano int
    )
});

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{insert into mody (ano) values (?)});

for (1 .. 100) {
    $sth->execute(int(rand(10)));
}

chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);
my @numbers = split(//, $input);

$sth = $dbh->prepare(q{select count(*) from mody where ano = ?});

for my $num (@numbers) {
    $sth->execute($num);
    my $count = $sth->fetchrow_array;

    say "$num: $count";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The DBD::mysql driver has a the rows() method that can return the count of the results:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( ... );
$sth->execute($num); 
$rowsCount = $sth->rows;
```

if you want to store it, you can do this :

```
$rowsCount[$num] = $sth->rows;
```

If you want to sum it :

`my $rowsCount = 0`  <-- before the  `for my $num(@num)`

then you can write :

```
$rowsCount += $sth->rows;
```

Comment: I did try using that method. But I couldn't figure out a way to store it in a variable

Comment: Do you mean an array  or do you want to display it like "rows matching input <$num>" ?

Comment: No. Like an array. I need to use that count value for further codes

Comment: The variable did get printed, but how do I get a sum of the total rows? It did gives it as 
1 row returned
1 row returned

Comment: Will you add an other question after every edit ? -_-

Comment: `rows` should not be used here. See [perldoc DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#rows). Too long to explain in a comment.